# How to insert font awesome in a liferay's custom theme?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

How can I insert and use font awesome 4 in a Liferay's 7.2 custom theme?

I saw in [Liferay's portal dev](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/frameworks/-/knowledge_base/f/using-font-awesome-and-glyph-icons-in-your-theme) that by selecting: Control Panel → Configuration → System Settings → Third Party, I could find a Font Awesome option, but that option is not in my panel.

Also in this [tutorial](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/6-2/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/creating-social-media-links-for-your-theme) it is explained how to use font awesome 3, but nothing about version 4.

Answer (score 0):

By default, **Liferay** use `Font Awesome v3.2.1`. I don't know if there is a way to change it.

If you want to use another version, then I suggest to add it in **package.json** file of your **theme**. It'll be the fastest and efficient way to add/customize the dependencies you want.

If you are okay with this solution, just don't forget to disable `Font Awesome v3.2.1` to improve performance of your portal.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have a package.json given that the theme was generated through IDE and probably it uses Blade instead of npm.